# How does Windows 10 find a routing rule in routing table?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, routing, routing-table

Consider the following routing table:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.8.1      192.168.8.2     2
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.20.20.1        10.20.20.35      6
```

Which routing rule is selected for ip "8.8.8.8"? Does Windows select the first matched rule(the bottom rule) or the rule with the lowest metric(the first one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. IP uses "longest prefix match" routing – out of all matching routes, the route with the most '1' bits in its netmask (i.e. the *most specific* route) is chosen.

Only if multiple routes with identical netmasks match the destination, then their cost metrics are compared, and the route with the lowest metric is chosen.

So if your destination is 8.8.8.8, then both routes will match, but the one with netmask 128.0.0.0 will have priority due to having more netmask '1' bits (i.e. a longer matching prefix). The metric is not used.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-tcpip-interfaces-interface-routes-route-metric
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb727001(v=technet.10)

Answer (score 2):

The bottom rule will be chosen.
The metric has no importance, because only this one rule matches.

The metric is only consulted if more than one rule is found that matches
the IP address, but here there is only one rule that matches.
The default route cannot match anything, so does not count.

Microsoft's article
[Metric](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-tcpip-interfaces-interface-routes-route-metric)
explains when metric is taken into account:

> Metric specifies the interface metric used to distinguish between multiple matching routes of the same prefix length. If multiple route prefixes match a packet destination, the route with the longest prefix length is preferred. **If multiple matching routes exist with the same prefix length, then the route with the lower metric is used**.

---

However, I have some doubts about the viability of the example as given
here in the post. As noted by user1686 below, this set of rules may
be incomplete.

The bottom rule is weird in the fact that its interface address, when
intersected with the netmask, gives only a zero.
By this it differs from any other example I have ever seen,
where the intersection always gave some non-zero number.

Comment: Routes don't have to correspond directly to an interface or even result in a valid network. They can cover any arbitrary address prefix, be it a single network or half a subnet or a supernet containing many interfaces, and as long as the route prefix matches the destination prefix then it'll work. This particular trick with installing two routes with /1 (or 128.0.0.0) netmask is often used by OpenVPN to override the default route – OP didn't show it, but I'm very sure there's also a 128.0.0.0/1 or "128.0.0.0 mask 128.0.0.0" route complementing this one.

Comment: @user1686: Yes, this example by itself is somewhat weird. OpenVPN assuredly handles it correctly, but I wonder if some routing algorithm somewhere could possibly get it wrong.

Comment: `because only this one rule matches` - I disagree. you can have many matching routes. That is why the bitmask is used to find the *longest* match, which is by definition the **best** match. `The default route cannot match anything` - this is '*the round-way wrong*'. The IP is matched against routes, and the point of a default route is PRECISELY to MATCH EVERYTHING (that did not get matched against any other more specific routes). Maybe trivial clarifications, but important nonetheless. Every bit counts...